# Why is my amazon s3 slow?

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a way to check that my files are already on the edge servers for my users to load from? Or does amazon s3 take time to spread your files around the world? How Long and can I receive notification about when?

So after I uploaded a file, I immediately tested the load speed by asking users from other far away places(like places in Japan). They said that it was rather slower than my current hosting in the US. That's odd because Amazon does have an edge server in Tokyo so Amazon s3 should be faster?

Before I created my bucket, I did set the region to be in the standard US. Is that why? If so, is there a way to set your files to work around the world?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you already said, your S3 buckets are situated in a specific location, for example us-east, europe, us-west etc. This is the place where your files are physically stored. They are not distributed geographically. Users from other places in the world will experience delay when requesting data from these buckets.

What you are looking for is the [Cloudfront CDN from Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). You can specify an origin (that would be your S3 bucket in your case) and then your files will be distributed to all the Amazon Cloudfront edge locations worldwide. Check out their [FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/) and the [list of edge locations](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/#details).

Comment: If you need to get faster access to S3 file from another region, try Nginx S3 proxy, it produces twice quicker SSL connection setup and downloading speed by using TCP optimization and reducing round-trips. https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog